# XMI tags with XSLT loops

Tags: xml, xslt, uml, xmi

I'm finding a problem with the xmi tags ( example : UML:Package) my real problem is that I can't use for-each loop with the select option (select="UML:Package") .
Here's the XML input code :

```html
<XMI xmi.version='1.2' xmlns:UML="org.omg.xmi.namespace.UML">
  <UML:Package type="stock" exch="nyse"   symbol="ZCXM" company="zacx corp"
        price="28.875"/>
  <UML:Package type="stock" exch="nasdaq" symbol="ZFFX" company="zaffymat inc"
        price="92.250"/>
  <UML:Package type="stock" exch="nasdaq" symbol="ZYSZ" company="zysmergy inc"
        price="20.313"/>
</XMI>
```

and here's my xslt code :

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"  xmlns:UML="org.omg.xmi.namespace.UML" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output indent="yes" />

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xmi:XMI>
   <xsl:for-each select="UML:Package">
    <stock>
     <xsl:attribute name="exchange">
            <xsl:value-of select="@exch" />
        </xsl:attribute>
     <name>
      <xsl:value-of select="@company" />
     </name>
     <symbol>
      <xsl:value-of select="@symbol" />
     </symbol>
     <price>
      <xsl:value-of select="@price" />
     </price>
    </stock>
    <hi>
    </hi>
   </xsl:for-each>

  </xmi:XMI>
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and this is what I get as a result :

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><XMI xmlns:UML="org.omg.xmi.namespace.UML"/>
```

with no erros on the console :

```
10:10:19,639 INFO  [main] Main  - javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory=org.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl
```

10:10:19,639 INFO  [main] Main  - java.endorsed.dirs=D:\PFE.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.xsl.jaxp.launching\endorsed
10:10:19,639 INFO  [main] Main  - launchFile: D:\PFE.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.xsl.jaxp.launching\launch\launch.xml
10:10:19,873 INFO  [main] JAXPSAXProcessorInvoker  - Transforming...
10:10:19,889 INFO  [main] JAXPSAXProcessorInvoker  - Done.

any help?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please provide enough code (XML+XSLT) to enable us to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your reported result is **not** what I get using your code. Your stylesheet has two major issues:

1. You are using a prefix `xmi:` without binding it to a namespace; this generates a parsing error and no result is produced.
2. From the context of your template - i.e. the `/` root node - the instruction:

   ```
   <xsl:for-each select="UML:Package">
   ```

   selects nothing. It needs to be:

   ```
   <xsl:for-each select="XMI/UML:Package">
   ```

Comment: and how to bind the xmi to namespace?

Comment: Add another namespace declaration to your `stylesheet` start tag, in the form of `xmlns:xmi="whatever.their.namespace.is"`.

Comment: Is there any possibility to get the node root without writing all of it ?

Comment: "*Is there any possibility to get the node root without writing all of it ?*" Sorry, I am not sure what you mean.

Comment: I meant I want to replace the "<xsl:for-each select="Root/UML:Package">" with a general expression in order to get the root of any node

Comment: I am afraid I am still not with you. Your XML does not have a node named `Root`, so that's confusing. --  If you want, you can use `*` for an element whose name you don't know - so `<xsl:for-each select="Root/UML:Package">` could be replaced by `<xsl:for-each select="*/UML:Package">` or even `<xsl:for-each select="*/*">`. If that's what you mean - I am just guessing here.

Comment: Yes that's what I'm looking for , but the '*' is not working for me .

Comment: I can't help you without being able to reproduce the problem. Perhaps you should post a new question?